# Rails - Sort and fetch all records below a particular record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table called SampleGroup which will have a column year. the year can have values like below year_1, year_2 and so on

The SampleGroup table also has position which sorts the records based on year column. The table will always looks like this.

```
| year     | position        |
| -------- | --------------  |
| year_1   |0                |
| year_2   |1                |
| year_3   |2                |
| year_4   |3                |
```

I want to fetch all the records that are below a given year for eg:

If given year_3, the query should fetch all the records below year_3 and year_3 should be returned. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: _"If given year_3, the query should fetch all the records below year_3 and year_3 should be returned"_ – the (only) record "below" year_3 from your example table is year_4. Yet, you want it to return (only?) year_3. Can you clarify?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your requirement, but wouldn't a simple `SampleGroup.where('year > ?', 'year_3')` return the expected results?

Comment: I thought the `position` column served an actual purpose, though - because perhaps one cannot assume that the years can be sorted lexicographically. For example, there might be a `year_10`.

Answer (score 1):

I would achieve this with two queries. First fetch the matching record, then fetch all records positioned below it:

```
year = 'year_3'
sample_group = SampleGroup.find_by(year: year)
SampleGroup.where('position <= ?', sample_group.position)
```